# Request defaults, use a function as default header

Tags: node.js, npm, request, npm-request

When using the NPM request module's request.defaults API, does anyone know of anyway in which I can pass a function as a request header, so that the function's result becomes the header value everytime I make an outgoing request?

i.e.

```
request.defaults({
    headers:{datestamp:() => new Date()
})
```

Answer (score 6):

It works with a getter method. You also need to use the instance returned from `.defaults`.

```
const Request = require('request');
const request = Request.defaults({
    headers: {
        get timestamp() { return new Date(); }
    }
})
request.get('/foo', ...);
```

Comment: I don’t know why I didn’t think of that. Thanks very much.